# How to disable Order cancel button in order view page in Magento admin?

Tags: magento-1

I want to disable the cancel order button from Magento admin order view page as well as from order grid page.

Though I know using the Roles we can disable this but I want to do this for some specific condition for a role.

So I am trying the code mentioned on the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788869/how-to-prevent-an-order-from-getting-cancelled-using-event-observer on stackoverflow.com 
Though the code does not hide the cancel button it try to prevent the order being cancel. But the code is not working for me and order is still canceled.

1) Do we have any approach using event observer to disable the particular button on order view page as well as order grid.

2) Do I need to override the `core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php` file?

Please suggest some solution for same.

[image: order grid]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case,Better idea to use ***Event/Observer***.

In magento,on class  `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container` there have a function `removeButton($id)`.

By using this function  and with help event `adminhtml_widget_container_html_before`,

You can **remove** `cancel` button from `order view`.

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
            <observers>
                <your_module>
                    <class>your_module/observer</class>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <method>adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore</method>
                </your_module>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

***Observer:***

```
public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($event)
{
    $block = $event->getBlock();

    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {

        $block->removeButton('order_cancel');
    }
}
```

You see more details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25565340/2940291

### [Edit:]

**remove cancel from order grid**

use `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before`

```
<!-- another events may which remove button from grid -->

<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            <observers>
                <remove_cancel_from_grid>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>your_model/observerr</class>
                    <method>removeButtoncancel</method>
                </remove_cancel_from_grid>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

***observer.***

```
public function removeButtoncancel($observer)
{   
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
        && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
    {
        $block->removeItem('cancel_order');
    }
}
```

As observer is `not works then try with block class rewrite` ***Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid***.

**Define rewrite in config.xml**

```
  <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtm

l>
```

**Rewrite class**

```
<?php
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid{


    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        parent::_prepareMassaction();
         $this->getMassactionBlock()->removeItem('cancel_order');    
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Get full module:

[Goto git hub](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento-stackexchange/tree/master/Disable%20Order%20cancel%20button%20in%20order%20view%20page%20in%20Magento%20admin)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution and if it works I will upvote.Do you know how can I remove the cancel action from actions dropdown.I do not want to use Role.

Comment: I tried the solution provided by you but it is not working.Control reaches to the methods but button is still there.

Comment: answered update and it working